# No package found for gnome fallback

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment

OK I installed fedora 22 and it came with gnome 3.16 which to be honest is the ugliest desktop environment I've used In my whole Linux experience.

As an ex kali user, I really adored fallback. But I don't think dnf has fallback.

I tried

```
dnf install gnome-session-fallback
dnf install gnome-session-fallback
dnf install gnome-flashback
```

And none were available packages.